# pyqt4 Segmentation fault (core dumped) when enabling plugins

Tags: python, linux, pyqt4, coredump

I'm working on a python web-browser using PyQt4/QtWebKit and I need to enable plugins so it can render flash content.

When I add this line I get a core dump QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)

**My System**

---

Linux rwilson-Aspire-E5-521 3.16.0-47-generic #63~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 14 22:56:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**PyQt Version**

---

('Qt version:', '4.8.6')
('SIP version:', '4.15.5')
('PyQt version:', '4.10.4')

**Here is all the code**

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork, QtWebKit
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebSettings

QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)

try:
    import jquery_rc3
except ImportError:
    import jquery_rc2


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.progress = 0

        fd = QtCore.QFile(":/jquery.min.js")

        if fd.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text):
            self.jQuery = QtCore.QTextStream(fd).readAll()
            fd.close()
        else:
            self.jQuery = ''

        QtNetwork.QNetworkProxyFactory.setUseSystemConfiguration(True)

        self.view = QtWebKit.QWebView(self)
        self.view.load(url)
        self.view.loadFinished.connect(self.adjustLocation)
        self.view.titleChanged.connect(self.adjustTitle)
        self.view.loadProgress.connect(self.setProgress)
        self.view.loadFinished.connect(self.finishLoading)

        self.locationEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.locationEdit.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                self.locationEdit.sizePolicy().verticalPolicy())
        self.locationEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.changeLocation)

        toolBar = self.addToolBar("Navigation")
        toolBar.addAction(self.view.pageAction(QtWebKit.QWebPage.Back))
        toolBar.addAction(self.view.pageAction(QtWebKit.QWebPage.Forward))
        toolBar.addAction(self.view.pageAction(QtWebKit.QWebPage.Reload))
        toolBar.addAction(self.view.pageAction(QtWebKit.QWebPage.Stop))
        toolBar.addWidget(self.locationEdit)

        viewMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&View")
        viewSourceAction = QtGui.QAction("Page Source", self)
        viewSourceAction.triggered.connect(self.viewSource)
        viewMenu.addAction(viewSourceAction)

        effectMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Effect")
        effectMenu.addAction("Highlight all links", self.highlightAllLinks)

        self.rotateAction = QtGui.QAction(
                self.style().standardIcon(
                        QtGui.QStyle.SP_FileDialogDetailedView),
                "Turn images upside down", self, checkable=True,
                toggled=self.rotateImages)
        effectMenu.addAction(self.rotateAction)

        toolsMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Tools")
        toolsMenu.addAction("Remove GIF images", self.removeGifImages)
        toolsMenu.addAction("Remove all inline frames",
                self.removeInlineFrames)
        toolsMenu.addAction("Remove all object elements",
                self.removeObjectElements)
        toolsMenu.addAction("Remove all embedded elements",
                self.removeEmbeddedElements)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(True)

    def viewSource(self):
        accessManager = self.view.page().networkAccessManager()
        request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(self.view.url())
        reply = accessManager.get(request)
        reply.finished.connect(self.slotSourceDownloaded)

    def slotSourceDownloaded(self):
        reply = self.sender()
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(None)
        self.textEdit.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.textEdit.show()
        self.textEdit.setPlainText(QtCore.QTextStream(reply).readAll())
        self.textEdit.resize(600, 400)
        reply.deleteLater()

    def adjustLocation(self):
        self.locationEdit.setText(self.view.url().toString())

    def changeLocation(self):
        url = QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput(self.locationEdit.text())
        self.view.load(url)
        self.view.setFocus()

    def adjustTitle(self):
        if 0 < self.progress < 100:
            self.setWindowTitle("%s (%s%%)" % (self.view.title(), self.progress))
        else:
            self.setWindowTitle(self.view.title())

    def setProgress(self, p):
        self.progress = p
        self.adjustTitle()

    def finishLoading(self):
        self.progress = 100
        self.adjustTitle()
        self.view.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(self.jQuery)
        self.rotateImages(self.rotateAction.isChecked())

    def highlightAllLinks(self):
        code = """$('a').each(
                    function () {
                        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow') 
                    } 
                  )"""
        self.view.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(code)

    def rotateImages(self, invert):
        if invert:
            code = """
                $('img').each(
                    function () {
                        $(this).css('-webkit-transition', '-webkit-transform 2s'); 
                        $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(180deg)') 
                    } 
                )"""
        else:
            code = """
                $('img').each(
                    function () { 
                        $(this).css('-webkit-transition', '-webkit-transform 2s'); 
                        $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(0deg)') 
                    } 
                )"""

        self.view.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(code)

    def removeGifImages(self):
        code = "$('[src*=gif]').remove()"
        self.view.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(code)

    def removeInlineFrames(self):
        code = "$('iframe').remove()"
        self.view.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(code)

    def removeObjectElements(self):
        code = "$('object').remove()"
        self.view.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(code)

    def removeEmbeddedElements(self):
        code = "$('embed').remove()"
        self.view.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(code)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        url = QtCore.QUrl(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        url = QtCore.QUrl('http://www.google.com/ncr')

    browser = MainWindow(url)
    browser.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an instance of `QApplication` before using `QWebSettings`.

Try moving the offending line to `MainWindow.__init__`.